# Using Ubuntu with any QWERTY keyboard layout is giving me a ? instead of a / when trying to press shift 7 to display /

Tags: keyboard, vnc, layout

I've tried ten different keyboard layouts, either I can't properly input _ or / is missing and is instead replaced with a straight up questionmark when pressing its keyboard shortcut. What gives?

I'm using Ubuntu install on my UnRAID and I'm viewing it through a VNC window

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: could it be an issue with the VNC setup as opposed to ubuntu?

Comment: @David using the latest LTS, 22.04.1

Comment: @24601 dunno? I'm using default VNC that's supplied with Unraid